# What is the right way for using ternary operator inside string templates?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a getter that has to return a different value depending on existed props. It looks like:

```
const converter = ({ propsValue }) => {
  return {
     get label() {
         return `${propsValue} ? ${propsValue} : ${anotherValue} ${secondAnotherValue}`
      } 
   }
}
```

The question is: What is the right syntax for the ternary operator inside string templates literals?

Comment: "What is the right syntax for the ternary operator inside string templates literals?" the same as anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put condition in brackets

```
const converter = ({ propsValue }) => {
  return {
     get label() {
         return `${propsValue ? propsValue : 'anotherValue'}`
      } 
   }
}
```

**With dynamic value**

```
return `${propsValue ? propsValue : anotherValue}`;
```

**With two dynamic values**

```
return propsValue ? propsValue : `${anotherValue} ${secondAnotherValue}`;
```

OR

```
return `${propsValue ? propsValue : anotherValue + ' ' + secondAnotherValue}`;
```

Comment: Sorry, but another value is also dynamic ${anotherValue}

Comment: @vmstr pass anotherValue to context  and modify getter `${propsValue ? propsValue : anotherValue}`

Comment: There are two 'another' dynamic values :)

Answer (score 0):

Answers are there for using the ternary operator

However, if you would like to look for a shorter and better one I would like to suggest one more thing if you just checking the first string in this way, you can also use it like

**Solution without using ternary operator**

```
return `${(propsValue ||anotherValue)}`
```

However, if you have  **multiple dynamic values** you can still use it as

```
return `${(propsValue ||anotherValue + oneMoreValueHere)}`
```

and to apply the same in your code,

```
const converter = ({ propsValue }) => {
  return {
     get label() {
           return `${(propsValue ||anotherValue + oneMoreValueHere)}`
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it inside the quotes would be 
`` return `${propsValue ? propsValue : anotherValue} ${secondAnotherValue}` `` 
yet a better way to do it would be using the or operator like this:
`` return `${propsValue || anotherValue} ${secondAnotherValue}` ``